# How can I use a different Apple ID to upload Apps

Tags: apple-id, developer-program, app-store-connect

How can I use a different Apple ID to upload my Apps to iTunesConnect?

The Apple ID that I use as Developer Account is also in use for uploading iBooks into iTunesConnect and can't be used to upload Apps anymore.

Is there a way to assign another Apple ID as developer account or to upload the Apps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is covered in the iTunes Connect guide under setting up user accounts:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH25-SW1